# What came first? Last Card or Uno?

Tags: uno, history

Which game came first?  According to Wikipedia, [Uno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_%28card_game%29) was invented in 1971, but I cannot find anything giving a date for [Last Card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Card)

Answer (score 3):

**Crazy Eights** was a very old game when I first played it in the early '60's.

Making a special deck to help remember the abilities of each rank (ie selling **UNO**) is brilliant entrepreneurship and marketing, but not a new game.

Comment: Crazy Eights does have variants (like Last One), but the base game doesn't have special abilities based on card rank. Do you have any sources showing the creation of a Crazy Eights variant matching the description of UNO/Last Card?

Answer (score 0):

A contributor, Mark Alexander, on [pagat](http://www.pagat.com/eights/last_one.html) notes that a similar game with a similar name **Last One** was invented sometime between  1970-1980.

> Mark Alexander reports that this variation of Crazy Eights (for 2 to 6 players) has been traced back to Walla Walla prison in Washington State, USA in the 1980's. Another correspondent tells me that she remembers playing it in the state of Maine, USA in the 1970's. [...]